# "Net Antennae Violation" on Pad -> Via -> GND plane connection

Tags: pcb-design, altium, design-rules

I just started routing my first PCB on Altium. It is a simple 2-layer board with bottom layer as dedicated GND plane.
I started out placing GND vias for GND pads of the top layer SMD components like this:

[image]

But Altium gives me a "Net Antennae Violation". The Altium documentation states:

> This rule operates at a net level in the design to **flag any track or arc end that is not connected to any other primitive** and thus forms an antenna. The specified value is the set tolerance of how long a stub must be before the rule will flag an error. **Default for this rule is set to 0**.

So I understand that a Via is no primitive and I could just disable the design rule. But I would like Altium to still warn me about something like this

[image]

while suppressing the GND via antennae violation.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Every time, when I am about to finish my PCB layout, I get this warning of 'Net Antennae'. But, the solution is simple:

You need to re pour all the polygons before you run the design rule check. In this way the violation does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you do not already have a ground plane below it? Also make sure your ground plane is on the correct net (ie, set the ground polygon to GND net). BTW, I just tested this using a "Solid Region" as my ground plane.

[image]

Comment: The GND plane is there but I used a Polygon Pour since I want it to pour around THT pads and other obstacles (which is common for power/GND plane IMO). You can see the thermal pad connections in the first picture (dimmed out though, thus gray). You are right that using a "Solid Region" prevents the error (it is probably treated as a primitive in contrast to the "Polygon Pour") but it does not really help me since it would be kind of a "dirty" workaround. Thank you anyway for your feedback.

Comment: did you try going back to the bottom layer and double clicking the poly? I just got this to work with a poly pour by (1) creating the pour and setting it to GND net (2) creating a trace off a ground pad (3) placing a via, setting it to GND net then (4) going back to bottom layer and double clicking poly to rebuild it. No net antennae violation.

Comment: I think it was some kind of bug. I deleted the existing polygon, placed a fresh one and now it works. I would say that everything is set up exactly like it was before. Since I did a lot of wild clicking and testing in this first design, maybe I somehow screwed it up. Thank you for verifying.

Comment: This was my issue. My RGE VQFN package describes a grounded "Thermal Pad" in the center. I added a large rectangle pour to the side opposite the chip, connected it to ground, and the warnings went away. Hoping the manufactured board works :)

Answer (score 1):

You may have a "hidden" track segment.

Click on the Via and on the track and on the pad. Check the multi-selector box carefully. There is probably an extra segment hiding in there that is causing the violation.

Comment: This came to my mind as well, but there is no hidden segment and since I got the error for every via of this kind it was unlikely.

Comment: JFYI, either it was a bug or I messed it up at some point. See comment on the other answer. Just placing a new polygon helped.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it worked out for you. :)