# Altium Designer 24 DRC error symbols meaning

Tags: pcb, antenna, altium, routing, drc

[image: PCB design in Altium Designer 24. Translator, resistors and capacitors]

I was wondering if anyone could help me understanding the DRC Net Antennae: via errors that look like lollipops. I've read that the double lines are related to un-routed net constraints.

Comment: An antenna is a wire that ends "in the middle of nowhere", without connecting to another component.  Is that what you're asking or could you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting the net antenna error markers on the vias because there is a small fragment of trace under the pad that is not visible, similar to the fragment that is visible below the U3 designator. They don't necessarily hurt anything as is, but you should fix them.

If you delete those fragments the errors will go away. Filter on **just tracks** then select sweeping over the pad then delete the bit that gets highlighted. Don't forget to clear the filter.

Answer (score 0):

A net antennae DRC error will be flagged for any track/arc without an end, or that ends in a via that is not connected to anything, and as such forms an antenna, as explained in the [Altium Designer 24 documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-manufacturing-rules#!net_antennae).

Either you have not connected the vias to anything, or you have some polygon pour that is shelved, not been poured yet, or you don't have any plane layers.

More can also be read in this
question: ["Net Antennae Violation" on Pad -> Via -> GND plane connection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152231/net-antennae-violation-on-pad-via-gnd-plane-connection)